# How to play or pause multiple instances of VLC simultaneously?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, vlc

I have 3 open VLC windows and whenever I see movement in one I need to pause all of them at once. Ideally I'd like a keyboard shortcut to do this. I tried AppleScript but I'm not familiar with the language and I can't see how to iterate through all processes of an application and tell each one individually.

Comment: If all three are actually playing something, how is it that you have more then one VLC window playing something?  I seem to only be able to play one object at a time.

Comment: This is useful: open `VLC.app` with `Script Editor` and check out the `VLC suite` to see all the `commands` and `properties` it has. It turns out we can use the `play` command to toggle playing, like this: `tell application "VLC" to play`  (but it won't solve the situation).

Comment: @user3439894 there are several ways to get multiple windows showing, e.g. https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC/ (the essential point there being `open -n` in the Terminal).

Comment: BTW: on this site it states: "On the Mac, running multiple instances of VLC is not supported out of the box." - but that is wrong since we can just use the VLC executable (which is "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC").

Comment: Well, it's supported by the OS, just not the VLC devs. I'll post a solution for this below

Comment: BTW, VLC has a "Motion Detect" video effect which marks motion with rectangles, sounds like  a good visual help. Hit CMD-E to open the "Video effects" window and select the "Color" tab and activate the option "Motion Detect".

Comment: @Froggard What I really meant is that `VLC Player` is also designed to be used as `command line tool`, using `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC` as `command`. Do `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --help`" in a `Terminal.app` window to get proof of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check for all instances of VLC and pause any of the instances that are currently playing something. Let me know if something unexpected happens! To create the shortcut, follow these steps:

1. Open Automator and create an Service, with a single Run AppleScript action, containing the following code:

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to repeat with VLC_instance in (application processes whose name is "VLC")
       tell the menu "Playback" of the first menu bar of VLC_instance
           if the menu item "Pause" exists then
               click menu item "Pause"
           else if the menu item "Play" exists then
               click menu item "Play"
           end if
       end tell
   end repeat
   ```
2. Set the service to receive "no input" and to work in "VLC" or "any application", if you want to ensure you can use the shortcut from anywhere. Save it with a name of your choosing.
3. Now, go into the Shortcuts tab in the Keyboard preferences in System Preferences, and click on Services. The newly created service should be at the bottom, under the name you chose. Click on the service, then click on "add shortcut", and specify a shortcut to your liking.
4. You may have to allow Automator access in Accessibility in the Privacy tab of the Security and Privacy preferences.

That's it! You should now have a service set up, tied to the shortcut you chose that can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Just a thought: this will probably fail when "Video=>Window decorations" is disabled (=no buttons) but the "Playback" menu should always work (I think).

Comment: That depends on whether or not the button is actually removed from the UI element hierarchy when that occurs (as it probably should be...). Your solution is probably safer though.

Comment: There we go! Now it should be fairly robust. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: hah, rewrote it in almost pure English just for the heck of it. I love AppleScript syntax. rofl...

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. I'd also like to be able to play the videos simultaneously again (probably should have mentioned that originally, edited the question for searchers). Since it'd be easier to have one shortcut for both I added an else clause:
 tell the menu item "Pause" of the menu "Playback" of the first menu bar of VLC_instance to if it exists then
  click it
 else
  tell the menu item "Play" of the menu "Playback" of the first menu bar of VLC_instance to click it
 end if. 
I'm guessing there's a better way?

Comment: @AlexHall If you want to toggle it you don't have to check for buttons. I tried this: ¨tell the menu item 1 of the menu "Playback" of the first menu bar of VLC_instance to click it'  and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. I considered that too but I thought it would be more robust to name the menu items explicitly. Anyway, now I have a new problem. The keyboard shortcut was working at first, but it suddenly stopped. It doesn't even work from the Services menu. It only works when I run it from Automator.

Comment: Yeah... It can be glitchy sometimes. Try repeating the last step, but uncheck Automator in the list first, then recheck.

Comment: Also, try the new code out.

Answer (score -2):

When you have one VLC "active" (in front of you) hit CMD+Q and it is ended.
And so with the next active one.

Comment: That would quit it, not pause, and the OP wants to pause all of them with one command.